# Typescript/TSLint - How to detect usage before assignment?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I want to get an error when using a variable before assigning it, like in:

```
   let a: number;
   let b = a;
```

So far I found out that setting the TS compiler option of strictNullChecks=true will detect that but it also shows me a lot of null assignment violations that I'm not interested in. I was hopping that TSLint would have a rule for that, but I couldn't find it.

Is there a TSLint rule or a TS compiler option that I can use for that besides the strictNullChecks?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be an exact setting that will hit the sweet spot for you. You'll have to choose where you want to land between these options...

If you stick with `const` by default unless you really have to allow multiple assignments, you can't create a `const` without assigning a value:

```
const: number; // ERROR! const must be initialized
```

If you want to catch the error of `let` non-assignment, then strict null checks are the way forward `strictNullChecks`.

Most of the errors you have can be solved by either tightening up the code, or loosening up the expression with an error (so that it allows nulls). Strict null checks is my preferred solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try to go the strict null checks route.